# Kubernetes Ingress not routing traffic to backend port

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

Ingress is not routing traffic to backend service port. Connection times out.

Any idea how to troubleshoot? There are no errors in the ingress controller logs.

```
curl -v -L https://www.example.com
*   Trying 172.20.xxx.xx:443...
```

I've checked the Loadbalancer and its health is fine. I'm not sure why its not routing traffic to backend port and what else I could check to figure out what the issue is.

Here is my aws `ingress controller.yaml` config :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:xxx"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.3.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And here the service config `service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-06T12:16:17Z"
  labels:
    app: manageiq
  name: httpd
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 100.69.xxx.xx
  clusterIPs:
  - 100.69.xxx.xx
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: httpd
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

`Ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-06T12:47:32Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: manageiq
  name: httpd
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: httpd
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: adc1d30f0db264d7ea54aed4dcdc12ec-atest.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Loadbalancer was set to internal. I was following a documentation.

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "false"
```

I had to delete services and recreate so a new load balancer gets created.

Comment: Note that while this works, the [docs](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/service/nlb/) say to use `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing`.